# Facebooker install on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authlogic

Hey guys, I'm trying to install facebooker using:

gem install facebooker

on my Win7 machine. It returns this:

> checking for ruby/st.h... ***
>   extconf.rb failed *** Could not create
>   Makefile due to some reason, probably
>   lack of necessary libraries and/or
>   headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for
>   more details.  You may need
>   configuration options.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.1, Gems 1.3.5 and Rails 2.3.5

I found this, to no avail.  I actually get the same error trying to install json gem.

http://blog.spaceprogram.com/2009/03/gem-install-facebooker-on-windows.html

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is there anything useful in the mkmf.log file?

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post might have the solution to your problem:
http://blog.spaceprogram.com/2009/03/gem-install-facebooker-on-windows.html

To quote the blog:

> To fix this:
>
> 1. gem install json -v 1.1.1 (only one that works on windows at time of
>      posting, json_pure doesn't work with
>      rails 2.3)
> 2. gem install facebooker --ignore-depencies

You can also try installing Facebooker as a plugin:

> script/plugin install
>   git://github.com/mmangino/facebooker.git